# Get related model data ember.js

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

I've essentially followed Ember's RESTAdapter conventions when building my restful api.

I have a model `post` and a model `tags`, a many-to-many relationship. Since I will only be finding tags that are related to posts I have not defined the inverse.

So I've got this in the post model `tags: hasMany('tag')` and in the restful api it returns `tags: ["1", "2", "3"]` and so on, just like it's suppose to.

So now I am wondering how I can get these tags on the `posts/1` url. When I look in the store it doesn't have any tags retrieved. How do I access the tag data and its properties?

```
App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr()
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    active: attr(),
    name: attr(),
    organization: attr(),
    user_id: attr(),
    submitted_ts: attr(),
    status: attr(),
    tags: hasMany('tag')
});

{
  "post": {
    "0": {
      "id": "1",
      "active": "A",
      "name": "This is a test title",
      "organization": "Stryker",
      "user_id": "0",
      "submitted_ts": "1402664380",
      "status": "finalized"
    },
    "tags": [
      "30",
      "1",
      "14"
    ]
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "30",
      "type": "asdf",
      "name": "KNEE",
      "pivot": {
        "case_id": "1",
        "id": "30"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "therapy",
      "name": "more things",
      "pivot": {
        "case_id": "1",
        "id": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "type": "therapy",
      "name": "asdfasdf",
      "pivot": {
        "case_id": "1",
        "id": "14"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The serializer is unrelated to this call

```
App.SpecialtySerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'specialty_id'
});


App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/v1',
    headers: function() {
        return {
            authToken: this.get('auth.authToken')
        };
    }.property("auth.authToken")
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused of what you're attempting, are you attempting to fetch the tags async, or are you wanting them to come down at the same time as the post?

Comment: come down at the same type as the post. My returned json is like 

`{post: { ... }} ..... tags: { ... }` the formatting is terrible, i know. But essentially the tags are in the json request of the post.

Comment: will you show your model definition for both post and tags above, and maybe toss up an example of the json, and you say you're using the RESTAdapter, does that still hold true?

Comment: Yeah, I am using the RESTAdapter.

Comment: And you are extending the serializer, can you include that?

Comment: Updated, although the serializer is not related.

Comment: Any idea as to what could be wrong? Even when I do a `save()` request it shows the `tags:[]` as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

when you have tags like this, you are saying the tag information is coming down with the request of the post.  If this isn't true, then you need to mark tags as async

`tags: hasMany('tag')`

if it included in the call to post, you need only access tags by doing `post.get('tags')`

Comment: Where should I be making this call? `post.get('tags')`? Should it be in the route?